# The symbol | is not written in the linux console

Tags: linux, console

Installed Linux without GUI, only console. I'm trying to enter a character | from the USB keyboard by pressing the corresponding button next to Enter. Without Shift it prints #, with Shift it prints ~. Tried all keys with Shift and without. How can I get the symbol |? Tried to iterate over characters with pressed Alt. Found that Alt + 124 writes the desired character, but maybe there is a simpler way?

Comment: I assume your keyboard mapping is wrong. This link https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration, although for arch, should apply to just about any distro.

Comment: `man ascii` will show you the character codes, so 124 is `|`, 47 is `/` etc if you need any other characters.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'm trying the command: 'localectl list-keymaps'.
Answer: Failed to read list of keymaps: No such file or directory.

Comment: Changing the keyboard mapping should be the right path. Besides to the Arch-Wiki, perhaps you also want to have a look here: [ask-Ubuntu: "Changing TTY keyboard layout on a server?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155424/changing-tty-keyboard-layout-on-a-server) and the over there linked [HowtoForge.com: "Changing The Language & Keyboard Layout On Various Distributions"](https://www.howtoforge.com/changing-language-and-keyboard-layout-on-various-linux-distributions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments! I added all the links in the answer.

Variants that work for any character:

1. To view the layout, enter the command `man ascii`
   Then type the desired character, for example, in my case it is `Alt + 124`
2. You can connect via SSH from another computer with a different layout and type the desired character there.
3. In my case, the problem was related to the locale. When installing, I chose British English, when reinstalling I chose Europe / Moscow, the problem disappeared.
4. If keyboard mapping is wrong, see on the link [wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration)
5. For changing the keyboard mapping, see on the link
   [ask-Ubuntu: "Changing TTY keyboard layout on a server?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155424/changing-tty-keyboard-layout-on-a-server)
   and link
   [HowtoForge.com: "Changing The Language & Keyboard Layout On Various Distributions"](https://www.howtoforge.com/changing-language-and-keyboard-layout-on-various-linux-distributions)